# RAM: which one is more better 2x2GB or 4GB?

Tags: laptop, ramdisk

Is this better to have **2x2gb DDR3 RAM** in both of the slot **or single 4GB DDR3 RAM** in single slot in laptop?
Which way is right to increase my laptop perfromances, what should I do for best and fast performances?

Comment: @root: No, I don't think so. The question you pointed to was "Is it better to have four times 2 GB or two times 4 GB of RAM?" and the accepted answer: "2 x 4 GB would be faster then 4 x 2 GB". In the current case quite the reverse is true: 2x2GB is better then 1x4GB

Comment: @dude - I don't see a difference.  There is no performance difference between `4x1` or `2x2` and `4x2` and `2x4`

Comment: @Ramhound: From the 110031: "Four sticks would cause more strain on the memory controller and motherboard chipset. It would take slightly longer for the CPU to add and retrieve data from four sticks as opposed to two.". So to say, 2 sticks are better as one (DDR3) AND better as 4 (of the same common size certainly)

Comment: @dude - You disagree this should be a duplicate but don't explain the why its not a duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound: I thought I did it :)

Comment: @duDE in their current form they are different questions..but nothing to do what what you speak of about one answer being a reverse of another.  They're diffferent questions because 4*2GB vs 2*4GB   Is a different question to 2*2GB vs 4GB. For example, it looks a bit like one question involves potentially quad channel, and no single channel configuration. Whereas this question is dual channel vs single channel. Though perhaps a question could be generalised.. quad vs dual vs single channel architectures/configurations, though general qs aren't always popular here, neither are too specific ones

Comment: @barlop: I agree, "reverse" may be a wrong wording ... Nevertheless you see the difference of this two questions and that was the point.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for 2 x 2GB slots - If 1 dies then you still are left with 1 stick which works but as well as that it works out cheaper for 2 slots and 1 slot, and the final thing I would point out is that some articles have worked out you get better output with 2 slots than using 1

Hope this helps

Comment: Also you can implement dual channel if your motherboard allows it.

Comment: in the past we kept reading that dual channel was better than single channel.. but maybe the jury is out. http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-the-Dual-Triple-and-Quad-Channel-Memory-Architectures/133   http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/326321-30-single-memory-dual-channel    http://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/1349-ram-how-dual-channel-works-vs-single-channel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dual channel ram (ddr2, ddr3) theoretically your RAM will run twice as fast with 2 sticks of 2gb.

The difference here is that with 1x4 you can only hit one channel at once, but with 2x2 you can hit 2 channels at once making your RAM twice as fast (it will of course not twice as fast, but it will be noticeable and good way to increase performance).